# Calculate each cells of columns and to put in another columns code vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code for my worksheet below:
[image: this my tab]

I want to calculate each cell in the "Quantity Prod" column ((G11 / Total: H4) * 100), and put in the column "Calculate defect".

Comment: You have the needed Formula in your question already. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I need code VBA

Comment: For what? Why isn't the formula suitable as well?

Comment: I wanted the code in vba because I have filtering by critere, so every time I perform a filtering of the date X up to Y date, I must have it automatically calculated for the row of "Calculate defect" and "Cumul Defect "To make a graph.
I do not know how to do the code in vba to compute each line of "Quantity_prod" and put the calculation of each row in the column "Calculate defect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code.
Just change the constants according to your needs.

```
Const SourceColumn As String = "G"
Const DestColumn As String = "L"
Const TotalCell As String = "H4"
Const StartRow As Integer = 11
Dim i As Long
i = StartRow
For i = StartRow To UsedRange.Cells(UsedRange.Cells.Count).Row
    Range(DestColumn & i).Clear
Next i
While Range(SourceColumn & i).Value <> vbNullString
    Range(DestColumn & i).Formula = "=(" & SourceColumn & i & "/" & TotalCell & ")*100"
    i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: This is what I wanted, but for "Const AndRew As Integer = 200" but for this code I need  just take the lines I filtered,

Comment: Because in the filtering the lines they are not fix

Comment: But the first row is fix? Can there be empty rows or would it be enough, to iterate through the rows, until an empty row appears?

Comment: The column G is not fixed it depends on filtering, for example sometimes I can have 500 line sometimes I can have more so "EndRow" it must take what is in column G

Comment: But it gives me that 0 in "Calculate defect"

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: In the column "Calculated defect" it calculates the filtered faults after the number 0 which displays for hundreds of rows

Comment: Please have another try on the now edited code. Please keep in mind that every time you refilter, the code has to be executed.

Comment: Does not work by the old code it passes the error I tell you

Comment: the is old code Sub calcul()
Dim ws As Worksheet
'set worksheet variable
Set ws = Sheet7

With ws

Const SourceColumn As String = "G"
Const DestColumn As String = "K"
Const TotalCell As String = "H4"
Const StartRow As Integer = 11
Const EndRow As Integer = 100

For i = StartRow To EndRow
   ws.Range(DestColumn & i).Formula = "=(" & SourceColumn & i & "/" & TotalCell & ")*100"
Next i
End With

 End Sub

Comment: Is there a possibility of you sending the file?

Comment: Sending what file?

Comment: No problem, kind to be of service.